# Using JQuery to access SonarQube Web API

Tags: jquery, sonarqube, sonarqube-api

My goal is to provide a dashboard page (HTML) with specific metrics for a list of projects.  To do this, I plan on using JQuery to retrieve and display those metrics.

So, I am trying to set up a JQuery function to retrieve data from SonarQube [Web API](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API) for a given component, and am having issues getting the Authorization correct.  I can pull the data I want with `curl` but cannot get the call JQuery to work.

This works (with appropriate definitions of `THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN` and `MY_SERVER` and `COMPONENT`):

```
curl -Ssu ${THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN}: "https://${MY_SERVER}/api/measures/component?component=${COMPONENT}&metricKeys=coverage"
```

But when I put this into an HTML document (with jquery/3.3.1 loaded) and load it in Chrome (with the same definitions for each of the variables) - I get a 401 error:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  `https://${MY_SERVER}/api/measures/component`,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN),
    },
    data: {
        component : `${COMPONENT}`,
        metricKeys : 'coverage',
    },
});
```

I even tried skipping the token and using my user and password:

```
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${USER}:${PW}`)
```

All with the same results -> 401.

*Note*: Chrome developer tools show a 401 response while Firefox shows 200 - for the same code. So I started to dump the response code directly from the ajax call, and both browsers agree 404.

Further testing - I used the Chrome developer tools to *Copy as cURL* the request, and pasted it on the command line (with all its glorious headers).  I had to add the `-u ${THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN}:` to the request as the copy/paste did not include the `Authorization` header (is this a known thing for security reasons?) - and it worked!

To me, this is just further evidence that it is an issue with how I am adding the header.

Any hints as to what I am missing in the JQuery?

Comment: Now I am even more confused... tried with just a URI of `.../api/authentication/validate` - so expecting just a `{"valid":false}` response.   The ajax call `error()` still gets triggered and shows a 404 error, but looking in the Chrome Developer tools - the Response to the call is correct!